# MDADM Default Chunk Size On Raid0 Install

Tags: ubuntu

What is the default chunk size for mdadm 2.6.7.1 and 3.1.4-1?

Will I get an option of chunk size when installing ubuntu server in raid0 or will it just setup the default chunk size

Answer (score 0):

Default chunk size is pretty small as you can find out Refering to The Fine Manual. But what the Manual won't say is using RAID0 is only okay when you absolutely don't care that there are as many more possibilities to have data loss as number of disks in RAID comparing to single one's failure probability. Any disk to fail means kiss your data goodbye.

Comment: Yes I understand that raid0 is not suitable for important data but the data in not important and I prefer to go with the performance boost that raid0 offers.

Comment: Can I specify 256k chunk size on a fresh ubuntu 11.04 raid0 install?

Comment: I doubt that. There're few chances it can be done with alternative or server installations though, so you tell us. ;-) Regarding boost — there's RAID-10, which gives both boost and safety. And RAID-1 which gives (from 2.6.2something) read "boost".

Comment: I just found out that mdadm 3.1.4 the current build used in ubuntu server 11.04 has a default chunksize of 512K rather than 64K.